# How to solve ORA-011033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress

Tags: oracle

I have followed [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676/how-to-resolve-ora-011033-oracle-initialization-or-shutdown-in-progress)  to solve the problem.

When it is giving `ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kcratr1_lostwrt]` then I am using:

```
SQL> startup mount
```

the above line should return `ORACLE Instance started`
but it is showing `"cannot start already-running Oracle - shut it down first".`

Comment: ORA-600 => go to Oracle's support site and search for the error. If no doc is found, open a case.

Comment: This is error you will get when the DB is corrupted. I had installed it once and got the same error. And the reasons for it can be not stopping the DB while you are shutting your PC down......This is my personal experience, so just thought to share it.

Answer (score 4):

ORA-00600 is Oracle's generic message for un-handled internal exceptions i.e. bugs.  Usually they require us to raise an SR with Oracle Support.    This can be a problem for sites who are using Oracle without a support contract.  In that situation we are thrown on the resources of the internet.

The problem you are experiencing is due to a corrupted block.  The top result in Google offers a simple workaround: [find out more](http://urisnotaword.wordpress.com/2010/05/17/ora-00600-internal-error-code-arguments-kcratr1_lostwrt/).

```
SQL> shutdown immediate;
SQL> startup mount;
SQL> recover database;
SQL> alter database open;
```

(Of course, this is only a solution if you are running in archivelog mode, and so can recover the lost block).

Answer (score 1):

Also I am guessing that you are running database on disks with write caching enabled. Or RAID controller with write cache enabled and no batteries or flash to preserve unwritten data.

**Do not do that if you value your data!**

Quite probably you will get some corruptions in case of crash reboot e.g. in case of power loss.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of using

```
SQL> alter database open;
```

command use  the follwing command

```
SQL> alter database open resetlogs;
```